# magento fooman google analytics add code twice in a page

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

fooman google analytics in magento 1.8 add google tracking code twice in a page. How to solve this issue?

I added google analytics extention of fooman. Problem is it add google analytics code twice in a page.

Answer (score 7):

**Problem:**

Fooman unsets the original google_analytics block via:

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>google_analytics</name></action>
</reference>
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>google_analytics</name></action>
</reference>
```

But in 1.8.1 the original google_analytics block has moved from position "after_body_start" to position "head", so unsetting no longer works.

Its an incompatibility with 1.8 Magento CE.

**Solution:**

Add these lines to your theme specific layout.xml file

```
<reference name="head">
           <action method="unsetChild"><name>google_analytics</name></action>
</reference>
```